# Include in Menu for all store views in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category

In Magento 2 when you edit a category by products / categories you can choose the option "include in menu". We have a multishop with several shops that use the same root category, but it is not possible to disable the include in menu for all the store views, only when you disable them per store view.

Is there a way to disable them all in one time or can you only disable them per store view?

Answer (score 0):

If the store views all use "Use default value" for the attribute "Include in menu", when you deactivate it at global level, it will be deactivated for all store views.
Otherwise you will have to do it for each store.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marius, unfortunately that is in Magento 2 as far as I can see not possible. I can't see "use default value" in a store view for the "Include in menu". By a lot of different category attribute that is possible. Any other thoughts?

Comment: if you don't see the use default value checkbox for include in menu it means that the attribute is global, so changing the value at default level or at a store view level will change it for all store views.

Comment: Thanks again, the strange thing is that I also expected that, but in our case that is not true, so if I change it in one the stores it does not change it by the other store views. So I have to do it per store view, can it be that this changed from Magento 1 to Magento 2? Would it help if I place two screenshots in my question, one from the all store views and one from the selected store view?